# Some CSS isn't being applied when I append a div with JQuery but it works fine when hard-coded

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the append function in JQuery but for some reason it won't work, it does apply some style but all regarding spacing as you'll see in the picture is gone for no reason but it is present on the hard coded example

**This is the code I'm using to append the  structure**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON( "JsonProd/Bolas.json", function( data ) {
                    var items = [];
                   $(".products_container, .grid").append('<div class="product grid-item hot">' + '<div class="product_inner">' + '<div class="product_image">' + '<img src="./images/BG.png" alt="">' + '<div class="product_image2"><img src="'+ data.camino_de_Imagen +'" alt="">' + '</div>' + ' </div> ' + '<div class="product_content text-center">' + '<div class="product_title"><a href="product.html">'+ data.Nombre_de_Producto + '</a>' + '</div>' + '<div class="product_price">' + data.Precio_del_Producto + ' ₡' + '</div>' + '<div class="product_button ml-auto mr-auto trans_200">' + '<a href="#">' + 'Consultar' + '</a>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>')
                    console.log( "ready" );
                });
            });  
</script>
```

**This is an example of the same code but hard coded into the place where I'm trying to append**

```
<!-- Products -->

    <div class="products">
        <div class="section_container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="products_container grid">   <!-- This is the div I'm appending to-->

                            <div class="product grid-item hot"> <!-- hard coded example-->
                                <div class="product_inner">
                                    <div class="product_image">
                                        <img src="./images/BG.png" alt="">
                                            <div class="product_image2"><img src="./images/balones.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="product_content text-center">
                                        <div class="product_title"><a href="product.html">Nombre Producto</a></div>
                                        <div class="product_price">20000 ₡</div>
                                        <div class="product_button ml-auto mr-auto trans_200"><a href="#">Consultar</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[appended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq2Av.png)

[Hardcoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4aR5.png)

Comment: If you get only image and some parameters from json, why not hardcode rest of it and change/add data?
As for difference, hard to say without looking at HTML's/snippet really.

Comment: It would work, however I need to append this same structure about 40 times with different "products" if it was just one I would save myself from the hassle of doing all the JSON and appending business

Comment: Don't see at as a problem. You need to append whole block 40 times instead of some data. Optionally you can AJAX this block with data and append whole html.

Comment: I'd suggest you to compare both the hardcoded html and the generated html using the browser's dev tools side by side, probably you'll see the diferences there.